# Beautiful Soup - Searching Between Two Parts of a Document

Tags: beautifulsoup

Is it possible to just run Beautiful Soup over content contained between two strings on a page?

Having repeatedly run up against the limitations of using Yahoo Pipes for screenscraping, I've started using Beautiful Soup, in part because a hosted version is available on Scraperwiki.

One of the handy things about the HTML Import block in Yahoo Pipes is that it lets you identify a start string and a stop string, so you can limit a scrape to a particular region of a page.

I found a way of scraping /from/ a particular string in Beautiful soup:

`def scrapeFrom(soup,txt,el,attr=''):

    start=soup.find(text=txt)

    return start.findAllNext(el,attr)`

but can't see how to dump everything downstream of a string?

That is, I want to be able to say "scrapeFromUntil(soup,fromText,untilText)" and only scrape tags between those two strings?

Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you wanted, but depending on the format of your HTML you may find [using SoupStrainer to limit parsing to only part of the document](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Improving%20Performance%20by%20Parsing%20Only%20Part%20of%20the%20Document) useful.